# Rendering VF page as PDF in Lightning

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

I have a question about an issue with rendering VF page as PDF in Lightning Experience (same code works fine with Classic).

I have a button that calls visualforce page which calls VF page and saves it as contentversion.

```
    PageReference pdf = Page.ZuoraQuotePDF;
    // add parent id to the parameters for standardcontroller
    pdf.getParameters().put('id', this.quoteId);

    Blob body;

    try { 
        body = pdf.getContent();
    } catch (VisualforceException e) {
        body = Blob.valueOf('There was an issue while generating Service Order. Please contact your Salesforce Administrator!');
    }
```

But it looks like that page is not rendered properly as file that is created is corrupted. Any ideas how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Are you trying to open a VF page in Lightning from the Community, or on the back end as a component?

Comment: did you try to use `getContentAsPDF();` instead of `getContent()`? and maybe the content type is not being specified